# TypeORM: findTrees() with condition

Tags: entity, typeorm

I have `Post` and `Comment` entity.

1 `Post` have many `Comment` (`OneToMany`).

`Comment` is a `Tree entity`.

When I access a `post`, I want to get all tree `comment` of that `post`.

The `findTrees()` only accept `depth` and `relations`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any lucks? i've been looking for a good solution but no luck yet.